# Issue with asyc/await + babel + react-native

Tags: react-native, build, async-await, babel-jest

My package.json from using the create react native app (although I manually upgraded to 0.48.1 for the `metro-react-native-babel-preset` package from 0.45.3):

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.48.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I'm using `yarn v1.10.1` and `node v10.12.0` and my `.babelrc` looks like:

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

My sample code for async/await is:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'

const MyStorage = {

  async saveItem(key, value) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value)
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  }
}

module.exports = { MyStorage }
```

I'm getting a build error:

```
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: myStorage.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (13:2)

> 13 |   async saveItem(key, value) {
```

How can I fix this? Is this a build configuration issue?

Comment: Did you try the following syntax for `saveItem`: `saveItem = async (key, value) => { ... }`?

Comment: I get the same SyntaxError Unexpected token error, but this time it points to the equal sign in `saveItem = async (key, value) => {`

Answer (score 0):

I kept my original syntax but added the following dev dependencies to package.json:

`@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator`

`@babel/runtime`